# passing ftp connection name as argument

Tags: coldfusion

I have created a `getImageFile()` function which requires the following arguments:

- ftp connection name
- remote file
- localfile

Within the function, ColdFusion throws an error that the connection is undefined.  But if I use the ftp connection name within the caller function then it works.

```
<cffunction name="getImageFile" access="private" returntype="string" >
    <cfargument name="ftpcon" type="any" required="yes" >
    <cfargument name="remotefile" type="string" required="yes" >
    <cfargument name="localfile" type="string" required="yes" >

    <cfftp action="GetFile"
           connection="#Arguments.ftpcon#"
           localfile= "#Arguments.localfile#"
           remotefile="#Arguments.remotefile#"
           stopOnError="false"
           transfermode="binary"
           failIfExists="false">

    <cfdump var="#cfftp#">
</cffunction>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: At what point do you open the connection?

Comment: Please include the error details. _You do not need to open a connection for single, simple, FTP operations, such as GetFile or PutFile._ From the [docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7349.html). The connection name is being passed to this function so I presume the connection is being opened elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the connection name argument `ftpcon` from your function. According to the [documentation found here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7349.html) (under the usage section) it is not required for simple operations such as `GetFile`.

> You do not need to open a connection for single, simple, FTP operations, such as GetFile or PutFile.

Of course, you will need to specify the `server, username, password` etc of the connection within your function.

The `connection` attribute of the `cfftp` tag is only required if the `action="open"` or `action="close"`.

That being said, you should also be able to use the cached connection (I presume) as you are trying to do. Please include the error details and I will update this answer if need be.